# jquery input field - get character by character

Tags: jquery

Im using jquery. And i need to get the input field value character by character.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var text = jQuery(selector).val();
var text_as_array = text.split("",text);
```

Now, `text_as_array` is an array that contains the input value as separate chars. Please remember that jQuery is just a library for Javascript and that Javascript can accomplish a lot of stuff without jQuery. Get more info  [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a different interpretation of your question than Mike, this will call your function every time the user enters a new character into the textbox

```
$("#youtextbox").bind("keyup", function() { // do something when the user presses a key });
```

Comment: If the user holds a key down, this will only fire once. Maybe use the newer `input` event.